# Should I get a game focused programming degree or a computer science one?

Tags: education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Game Development Degree vs Computer Science Degree](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/game-development-degree-vs-computer-science-degree)

Heres the best education I got in ky math is AP Calculus and no technology class that teaches a programming language. So should I just go get a Computer Science degree or a game programming-based one? Might not be a lot; ask if you need more info to decide.